# CakePHP not able to login with email

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I want to add some basic authentication to my app. So I mostly followed the cookbook tutorial but I want to sign in with my email instead of a username. So I wrote following lines:

**AppController.php**

```
public $components = array(
  'Auth' => array(
    'authentication' => array(
      AuthComponent::ALL => array(
        'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
      )
    )
  )
);
```

**UsersController.php**

```
public function login() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
      $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid email/password combination'));
  }
}
```

**login.ctp**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end(__('Login'));
?>
```

**User.php**

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
  $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
  return true;
}
```

I created a user before but I am not able to login. What am I doing wrong? I am getting crazy...

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Is there an error or anything else going on?

Comment: Only the flash message I defined in the login method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) the array should look like this:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**DAMN IT**

Instead of `'authenticate' => ...`, I wrote `'authentication' => ...`.